# Oracle SQL Case when statement with dates and times

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle's SQL and I'm trying to change following SQL Server query to run in Oracle SQL Developer ;

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART (Hour,  OpenTime) < 5
     THEN CONVERT(TINYINT,DATEPART(hour, OpenTime) + 24)
     ELSE CONVERT(TINYINT,DATEPART(hour, OpenTime))
      END
```

Following is one of my attempts but it gave me an error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN TO_CHAR(CAST(Opentime AS TIMESTAMP),'HH24') < 5 
       THEN  TO_CHAR(CAST(Opentime AS TIMESTAMP),'HH24') + 24
       ELSE TO_CHAR(CAST(Opentime AS TIMESTAMP),'HH24')
        END 
  FROM Impos_BI_User.tbl_check
```

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to get `24` hours added while hour portion of the `OpenTime` column, which seems to be of `DATETIME` type, has values between `00` and `04`.

As `DATEPART(Hour,  OpenTime)` returns integer value, you used `< 5`, i.e. only integer part, and in Oracle DB, `TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(OpenTime,'hh24' ) )` conversion would be equivalent to this.

Let's alias this `hour` within a subquery, in order not to repeat this conversion for each need :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( OpenTime,'hh24' ) ) AS hour
  FROM t
)
SELECT CASE WHEN hour < 5
            THEN hour + 24
            ELSE hour
             END AS hour
  FROM t2
```

or alternatively, use `DECODE()` function Conditional Expression spesific to Oracle :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT to_number( to_char(OpenTime,'hh24') ) AS hour
  FROM t
)
SELECT DECODE( SIGN( hour - 5 ), -1, hour + 24,  hour ) AS hour
  FROM t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=146024f99159ab48a9714d0478ba13e8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MS SQL Server so I'm guessing: if hours (extracted from some date value) are less than 5, you want to add 1 day (i.e. 24 hours) to that date value; otherwise, leave it *as is*.

If that's so, see this example:

```
SQL> with test (id, opentime) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (-- ID = 1: it is 7 hours here, no changes to be made
  4     select 1, to_date('18.04.2020 07:12', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  5     union all
  6     -- ID = 2: 2 hours, which means that 24 hours should be added
  7     select 2, to_date('01.04.2020 02:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  8    )
  9  -- your query
 10  select id,
 11    case when to_number(to_char(opentime, 'hh24')) < 5 then
 12              opentime + 1
 13         else
 14              opentime
 15    end result
 16  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- ----------------
         1 18.04.2020 07:12
         2 02.04.2020 02:20

SQL>
```

- in sample data, `TO_DATE` function makes sure that those really are `DATE` datatype values, not e.g. strings
- line #11: no need to cast anything; just apply appropriate functions tho those values
- line #12: in Oracle, date arithmetic works on *days* so I added `1 day` (which is 24 hours you used).

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract()`!

```
(case when extract(hour from opentime) < 5
      then extract(hour from opentime) + 24
      else extract(hour from opentime)
 end)
```

Oracle has a [perfectly good function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) that returns the integer hour.  You should use it.  As a plus, this is a standard SQL function.